# Meaning of "over" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, american-english

I am reading an academic article and there is a key sentence in the discussion that can change the whole idea.

> "The metric used is mean average precision, which calculates the mean
> of the average precisions over all the images"

I am not sure about the role of "**over**" in this context. Does the sentence mean "calculating a precision for each image individually and then average the precisions"?

Comment: Provide more context

Comment: Yes, over means including, covering.

Comment: As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+average+across+all%2Cthe+average+over+all&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20average%20across%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20average%20over%20all%3B%2Cc0) shows, we very often use ***across*** with exactly the same meaning as ***over*** in such contexts. They're both "surface metaphors".

Answer (score 2):

Over in this context means *across the entire set*, and is generally used in mathematics across sets, fields, matrixes, and other related entities.

For instance, this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730254/function-defined-over-a-set-or-on-a-set) from Math SE notes that Wikipedia uses this terminology for "Algebra over a field".

An [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=average%20over%2Caverage%20on%2Caverage%20across&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caverage%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caverage%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caverage%20across%3B%2Cc0) shows that *average over* is more popular than *average on* or *average across*, which have the same meaning. It's possible this ngram includes material unrelated to this context, but the trend is very strong.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field)

Comment: I think your NGram might be picking up a lot of "false positives". [This chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=average+across+all+states%2Caverage+over+all+states&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) strongly suggests that *average **across** [data sources]* has increasingly displaced *average **over*** over recent decades...

Comment: ... but [we still stick with ***over***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=across+recent+decades%2Cover+recent+decades&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacross%20recent%20decades%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cover%20recent%20decades%3B%2Cc0) for ***recent decades**!* :)

Comment: Google NGram isn't going to tell you what is the standard usage in math or computer science.

Comment: @jimm101, does it mean calculating a value on "each and every" query individually and then calculate average of those individually-calculated values to get ONE number?

Comment: Exactly. You get an array (set) of average precisions, and then you take the mean of that array (set). It seems like this is all very loosely written. Unless "average" is defined elsewhere, they likely are saying "a mean of the means". And since that is over all images, it can just be one big mean over the entire set of measurements.